# How to add a tablix control to a report?

Tags: ssrs-tablix

This seems like a simple question but I cannot find anything on adding a tablix control to an SSRS report.

I don't see this control in the toolbox in bids or in report builder 3.0.

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2.

Can someone kindly tell me how to add this control to a report?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220587(v=sql.105)):

> The table, matrix, and list data regions are represented on the ribbon by templates for the underlying tablix data region. When you add one of these templates to a report, you are actually adding a tablix data region that is optimized for a specific data layout. By default, a table template displays detail data in a grid layout, a matrix displays group data in a grid layout, and a list displays detail data in a free-form layout.

Could it be any more unintuitive?